# Angularjs HTTP POST call to authenticate login in deployd failed- 400 error returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-post, deployd

Trying the below http post request in angularJS to deployd, with a Collection users containing data username and password,

```
  angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin")
    .constant("authUrl", "http://localhost:2403/users/login")
    .controller("authCtrl", ['$scope','$http','$location','authUrl', function($scope, $http, $location, authUrl) {

      $scope.authenticate = function (user, pass) {
        $http.post(authUrl, {
          username: user,
          password: pass
        }, {
          withCredentials: true
        }).success(function (data) {
          $location.path("/main");
        }).error(function (error) {
          $scope.authenticationError = error;
        });
      };

  }]);
```

when trying to authenticate login using above url to deployd, deployd is giving below error:-

http://localhost:2403/users/login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).

what could be the issue?

Comment: post the code for the controller handling the request, the method is expecting something different than what you are passing

Comment: Deployd generates it's api kind of tool... Controller code in backend is not written by me

Comment: Add screenshot of what error u face

Answer (score 0):

The following code would be the best way to login a user:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  dpd.users.login({username: username, password: password}, function(session, error) {
    if (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    } else {
      location.href = "/welcome.html";
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Being 'form' a HTML login form, and **#username** and **#password** being input tags with their respective ids.

**See this example for more references:**
https://github.com/deployd/examples

Comment: @Aravind My bad! I misunderstood the question and I was referring to posting objects in a collection. 
I have updated my answer!

Comment: fine. But create a sample app and try executing this logic!